# How to convert a rational number to string with specific amount of decimals in Java?

Tags: java

The problem is as follows: In our RatNum class in Java there is an int a(nominator) and int b(denumerator) among some methods, for this project a method "toDotString" is required which is the only one I haven't managed solving. The method takes an argument decimalCount and then returns a string with the value rounded towards 0. So for example r=1/3, r.toDotString(3) should return 0.333. The use of BigDecimal, float, double, etc is not allowed.

I've managed to solve it for all cases except for the cases where it starts with 0 followed by decimal(0.xxx).

```
public String toDotString(int decimalCount){
    int x = a/b;
    String num=String.valueOf(x);
    num= num + ".";
   
    int rest=a-(x*b);

    if(x!=0){
        rest=(rest*(int)Math.pow(10,decimalCount))/b;
        if(x<0){rest=rest*-1;}
    }
    String decimal=String.valueOf(rest);
    if(rest==0){
        for(int i=1; i<decimalCount; i++){
            num=num + "0";
        }
    }
    num= num + decimal;
    return num;
}
```

This is what works for the cases above 0.xxx.

Next piece of code is what was tried to fix it.

```
if(x==0){
        
        String denominator=String.valueOf(b);
        boolean MultipleOfTen=true;
        if(denominator.charAt(0)=='1'){
            for(int i=1;i<denominator.length();i++){
                if(denominator.charAt(i)!='0'){
                    MultipleOfTen=false;
            }
        }
    }else{MultipleOfTen=false;}
    if(MultipleOfTen){
       for(int i=2; i<denominator.length(); i++){
           num=num +"0";
        }
    }else if(a>(denominator.charAt(0)-'0')){
        for(int i=2; i<denominator.length(); i++){
           num=num +"0";
        }
    }else{
       for(int i=1; i<denominator.length(); i++){
           num=num +"0";
        } 
    }
        int k=decimalCount-(num.length()-2);
        int dec=(int)Math.pow(10,(k+denominator.length()-1))/b;
        String Decimal=String.valueOf(dec);
        num=num+Decimal;
        if(MultipleOfTen){num=num.substring(0,num.length()-1);}
       
        if(a<0){num="-"+num;}
        return num;
    }
```

This is how I tried doing it for the x==0 case but it doesn't work for all cases tested. I also feel that there is a simpler way to do all of this so any recommendations are greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) answer your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.4f", 1. / 3);    // 0.3333
```